# Converting dynamic web project to maven takes too long a time

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I am beginning to learn Spring MVC. I have created a dynamic web project in eclipse successfully, now I want to convert it into a maven project project using the following steps Rightclick on my root folder > Configure > Convert to maven project. Using the above step takes too long to generate pom.xml as shown in the screen shot.

[image]

Please is there a step I am missing. Kindly assist!

Comment: Do you have unrestricted internet access? I think at this step Eclipse/Maven tries to connect to Maven Central to load Maven plugins and dependencies, which might not work in restricted environments.

Comment: Create a maven project directly. Why are you creating a dynamic project and the converting it to maven

Comment: Please what is the practical importance of maven to spring mvc

Comment: Only *"takes too long"*? Does it finish in the end?

Comment: I interrupted the process a couple of times because the process is more than 15 mins

Comment: Every thing is fine now I think my internet connection is slow